# Performance of IndexOf(char) vs Contains(string) for checking the presence of a character in a string

Tags: c#, string, performance, contains, indexof

I want to know if

```
string.IndexOf(char)
```

is *faster* than

```
string.Contains(string)
```

Intention is to check if a *single character* is present in a `string`. I know that as per requirement I should use `string.Contains(string)` but that is not the point of this question. I did try to *disassemble* `mscorlib.dll` in an attempt to compare their implementations but I could not find the implementation of

```
 string.IndexOf(char)
```

as it is implemented within the *CLR itself*. Implementation of

```
 string.Contains(string)
```

looks quite *heavy* though.

Comment: Why don't you try doing a test?

Comment: [*"If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses** ... Even if by sheer chance you got an accurate answer, how would you have any confidence in its accuracy? **You can easily and accurately discover which of two programs is faster by running both yourself and measuring them with a stopwatch.**"*](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: To answer your question, I read numerous times that IndexOf() is faster

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just test and see

```
  String source = new String('a', 10000000) + "b" + new String('c', 10000000);

  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();

  // Just an estimation
  int result = source.IndexOf('b');
  // int result = source.IndexOf("b");
  // Boolean result = source.Contains("b");
  // Boolean result = source.Contains('b');

  sw.Stop();

  int time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

At my workstation (i5 3.2 GHz, .Net 5.0 64 bit) it takes about **10 ms** for `Char` and **38 ms** for `String`

**Edit:** Performance's outcome is

```
  IndexOf(Char)     10 -- Fastest
  IndexOf(String)   38 
  Contains(Char)   100 -- Slowest
  Contains(String)  41
```

so `IndexOf(String)` and `Contains(String)` are roughly the same

Comment: What about `Contains()`?

Answer (score 3):

Source code for `mscorlib.dll` is available (and has been at the time of the original post) at [Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib). You can see there in `String` class, that Contains(string) is a wrapper

```
public bool Contains( string value ) {
    return ( IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0 );
}
```

around `IndexOf` function, which is using extern `InternalFindNLSStringEx` function, that must be pretty fast. But not so fast, as extern `IndexOf(char)` function, for obvious reasons.
This explains, why the calculation speed for `IndexOf(string)` and `Contains(string)` is nearly the same. But be careful with your becnhmarks, because deep down in CLR it uses some sort of caching, I think, so the speed of one function depends on in which order you call it - before or after another.

This question wasn't present in original post, but as someone above mentioned this, let's also look at `Contains<char>` which is an `Enumerable` extension:

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    foreach (TSource element in source)
        if (comparer.Equals(element, value)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

So, it is going to call `Equals` on every element in sequence. This is neat, and allows you to use custom comparer, but using `IndexOf(char)` would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should write a small benchmark to find out.
2. I predict this outcome: since `IndexOf(char)` is a simple loop and
   `Contains()` (and `IndexOf(string)`) is usually two nested loops,
   the former will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test similar to [Dmitry Bychenko's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279933/performance-of-indexofchar-vs-containsstring-for-checking-the-presence-of-a#28280043), but ran each test 1000 times. For each iteration, I generated a new, pseudo-random 20,000,001-character long string to avoid any distortion of results caused by any caching that might be happening. Looking at the .NET source code, it seems like most of these methods are ultimately calling unmanaged code, as [Konstantin K. pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279933/performance-of-indexofchar-vs-containsstring-for-checking-the-presence-of-a/76336526#51366792). And it appears that there *can* be a big difference in performance depending on whether your string can be an ASCII string or whether it contains Unicode characters. Check out that `source.IndexOf("範")` in .NET Core 6 below!

I ran the same tests in a .NET Framework 4.8 console application and a .NET Core 6.0 console application. Here are the results:

### .NET Framework 4.8

```
"ASCII" String:
source.IndexOf('b')     Median:    2 ms    Average:   2.462 ms
source.IndexOf("b")     Median:   54 ms    Average:  55.432 ms
source.Contains('b')    Median:   46 ms    Average:  47.869 ms
source.Contains("b")    Median:   12 ms    Average:  12.773 ms

String containing Unicode characters:
source.IndexOf('範')    Median:    2 ms    Average:   2.030 ms
source.IndexOf("範")    Median:  116 ms    Average: 116.324 ms
source.Contains('範')   Median:   43 ms    Average:  43.218 ms
source.Contains("範")   Median:    7 ms    Average:   6.621 ms
```

### .NET Core 6.0

```
"ASCII" String:
source.IndexOf('b')     Median:    0 ms    Average:  0.305 ms
source.IndexOf("b")     Median:   16 ms    Average: 15.789 ms
source.Contains('b')    Median:    0 ms    Average:  0.099 ms
source.Contains("b")    Median:    0 ms    Average:  0.300 ms

String containing Unicode characters:
source.IndexOf('範')     Median:   0 ms    Average:   0.354 ms
source.IndexOf("範")     Median: 259 ms    Average: 259.086 ms
source.Contains('範')    Median:   0 ms    Average:   0.027 ms
source.Contains("範")    Median:   0 ms    Average:   0.351 ms
```

### BUT ...

How many times are you going to search a 20 million character long string for a single character? And how many times would you find yourself doing that 1000 times in a row? The point being that an end user probably would never notice if something took 2 milliseconds or 40. No need to do micro-optimizations, unless you truly need to. (And avoid `String.IndexOf(String)` with Chinese characters in .NET Core!)