# c# get substring of enum value

Tags: c#, enums, string-comparison

Is there a clever way to get an enum value by comparing a substring a la `String.Contains` with the enum?
I checked this implementation ([Convert a string to an enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp)), but would like to have an intelligent extension doing the same but including substrings comparison, something like `TryParse` with an option to check the whole substring of the enum values.

```
    public static void Main()
{
    string a = "HANS";
    GetName(a); // prints Hans
    
    string a1 = "Peter";
    GetName(a1); // should print enum value "WolfgangPeterDietrich " containing the substring "Peter"
}

public enum MyNames
{
    Hans = 0,
    WolfgangPeterDietrich = 3,
}

public static void GetName(string a)
{
    MyNames dif;
    // this works fine, ignore case
    if (Enum.TryParse(a, true, out dif))
    {      
        System.Console.WriteLine(dif.ToString());
    }
    // ToDo: check for substring ??
}
```

Comment: What if more than one enum value contains the substring?

Comment: `Enum.GetNames<Names>().Where(n => c.Contains(a, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))` might be a start?

Comment: Also, if it don't find, what it should print? Is it case sensitive or insensitive?

Comment: First occurence should be fine, and if it dont find, just do nothing is fine

Answer (score 1):

This approach takes the first occurrence found, and is case insensitive.

```
public static void GetName(string a)
{
    string? result = Enum.GetNames<MyNames>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(a, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    System.Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: that does exactly the job, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: just changed to ```Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyNames)).FirstOrDefault```

Answer (score 0):

Just a prototype to fix with boundary cases and assertions:

```
public static T EnumNameContains<T>(string substringOfName) where T: struct
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), 
        Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault(
            name => name.IndexOf(substringOfName,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0));
}
```

I guess can help.

Comment: nice one following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279933/performance-of-indexofchar-vs-containsstring-for-checking-the-presence-of-a

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public static void GetName(string a)
        {
            MyNames dif;
            // this works fine, ignore case
            if (Enum.TryParse(a, true, out dif))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(dif.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                var result = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyNames)).Where(dd => dd.Contains(a, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
                System.Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            
        }
```